# Semantic UI onSuccess, onFailure callbacks not being fired upon form validation

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

In the following code which validates that username has a value and that the passwords match, neither the onSuccess nor the onFailure callback is ever fired even though the validation rules are being executed/enforced.  I've tested every other part of this independently and this layout follows the documentation exactly, so I've ruled out syntax errors. In addition to the syntax used below, I also tried the format of $().form().onSuccess().onFailure() but got an "Uncaught TypeError: onSuccess is not a function".  Fiddle here:  [Semantic UI onSuccess, onFailure callback example](https://jsfiddle.net/dhswain/6y7w57xv/1/).

```
$(function(){
    $('#main')
        .form({
            on: 'blur',
            fields: {
                username: {
                    identifier : 'username',
                    rules: [
                        {
                            type : 'empty'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                password1: {
                    identifier  : 'password1',
                    rules: [
                        {
                            type   : 'match[password2]',
                            prompt : 'Please enter the same value in both fields'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                password2: {
                    identifier  : 'password2',
                    rules: [
                        {
                            type   : 'match[password1]',
                            prompt : 'Please enter the same value in both fields'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            onSuccess: function() {
                $(".ui.button[name='account']").removeClass('disabled');
                console.log('Success');
            },
            onFailure: function() {
                $(".ui.button[name='account']").addClass('disabled');
                console.log('Failure');
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: I just updated the code on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6y7w57xv/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to call it this way. `$('#main').form(fieldRules, settings);`
`onFailure` and `onSuccess` are registered in settings.

Have a look of revised code:

```
    $(function(){
        $('#main')
            .form({
                    username: {
                        identifier : 'username',
                        rules: [
                            {
                                type : 'empty'
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    password1: {
                        identifier  : 'password1',
                        rules: [
                                {
                                    type: 'empty',
                              prompt: 'Please enter the password'
                                },
                            {
                                type   : 'match[password2]',
                                prompt : 'Please enter the same value in both fields'
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    password2: {
                        identifier  : 'password2',
                        rules: [
                            {
                                type   : 'match[password1]',
                                prompt : 'Please enter the same value in both fields'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }, {
                    on: 'blur',
                  inline: true,
                  onSuccess: function() {
                    alert('Success');
                    return false; // false is required if you do don't want to let it submit

                    },
                    onFailure: function() {
                    alert('Failure');
                    return false; // false is required if you do don't want to let it submit                                            
                    }
                  });
    });
```

Comment: That doesn't work at all - the validation doesn't even run now. Plus putting `on` and `inline` in the first object work just fine, so why wouldn't `onSuccess` and `onFailure`? I made sure to remove the wrapping `fields: {}` in the first object, and still nothing happens.

Comment: Aha! At least in latest versions (2.2.x), you do *not* use a second settings object. OP actually has the right code already - the problem is there is an unintuitive behavior with the `onSuccess` and `onFailure` callbacks, particularly in my case when I'm working with a single-field form. They are **not** called when validation finishes based on the `on` method. ie: `on: 'blur'` or `on: 'change'` does not mean `onSuccess` will be called as soon as the last field validates. You *must* submit the form or, in the case of a single-field form, use the `onValid` event instead.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well. I tried everything, the only way I could onSuccess to fire was doing this:

```
  const formValidated = $('.ui.form').form(
     {
        fields: {
           name: {
              identifier: 'name',
              rules: [ 
                 {
                    type   : 'empty',
                    prompt : 'Please enter a name for the camera'
                 }
              ]
           },
        }
     }
  )

  if ($(formValidated).form('is valid')) {
     this.handleSave();
  } else {
     return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

After several hours of having this issue, I've found this works for me (semantic ui @2.4.1, jquery @3.1.1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#message-center form').form({
    fields: {
      email: {
        identifier: 'email',
        rules: [
          {
            type: 'empty',
            prompt: 'Please enter your email.',
          },
          {
            type: 'email',
            prompt: 'Please enter a valid email.',
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    onSuccess: function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      sendMessage(event);
      return false;
    },
  });
});
```

Observe that `onSuccess` is on the same options object as `fields`.